# Java GregorianCalendar What am I doing wrong? Wrong date?

Tags: java, date, time, gregorian-calendar

Hello I have a problem with GregorianCalendar.

What is wrong in there?

How outcome is 2010/6/1 and not 2010/05/31?

```
package test;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2010, 5, 31);
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java counts months from 0, so 5 is June. It's always safer to use the constants. So I would write:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2010, Calendar.MAY, 31);
```

The same applies to your calendar print out. If you do `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)` you get 6 meaning JULY.

Answer (score 1):

This is because month number is zero-based, so you are trying to set 31st of June, but June is only 30 days, so it gets converted to 1st of July.

Answer (score 1):

Toadd to what the above answers, since there is no 31st day in June the Calendar promotes it to the next valid day because [Calendar.setLenient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) is true by default.